# Entity Framework and split string?

Tags: linq, entity-framework

When getting entities from database I do something like this :

```
using (MyAppEntities context = new MyAppEntities ())
{
    adCategoryPresets.AddRange(context.AdCategoryPresets.Where(...).ToList());
}
```

The problem now is that AdCategoryPresets contains a column(string) that I need to split(",") and then compare to a integer. Is this possible? I can´t get it to work? Is there another way?

**Edit1:** The string that I need to compare my int to could look like this :

"5,6,9", "52,55,3" or just "5"

Comment: Would it be possible to use regex instead?

Comment: In what way do you want to _compare to a string array_?

Comment: Sorry, have updated it now, also note that its not a array but a integer Im looking for.

Comment: OK, but what do you mean by _compare_? See if the integer is in the string?

Comment: Say that I need to check for 5 in the string, the problem is that "55,55,3".Contains("5") will return true while its should be false in this case.

Comment: Looks like you should check for `== "5"`or `Contains(",5")` or `Contains("5,")` if you want to have your expressions translated to SQL. (It must even be done smarter, ",55," still matches).

Comment: I Supose that I could change the way the string is storead and let every value start with a "|" and always end with a "|". Like this "|5|", "|2|55|23|553|" This should make it easy. int 5 will be translated to the string "|5|" and then runt "|2|55|23|5|553|".Contains("|5|") would be true while "|2|55|23|553|".Contains("|5|") would be false. But is this really the way? Is there no simpler way with entityframework?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7346/discussion-between-gertarnold-and-snowjim)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was solved by adding "|" to the start and end of the string like this "|2|55|23|553|" this makes it easier to match for example "|5|".

Comment: This is a slick solution that works on strings too. Of course, this only works if you are allowed to redefine the storage format in the DB.